# Custom table filter JavaScript/jQuery script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have four checkboxes to filter four categories of table data.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="audio" id="music_filter">
<input type="checkbox" value="video" id="video_filter">
<input type="checkbox" value="writing" id="writing_filter">
<input type="checkbox" value="game" id="games_filter">

<table>
<tr class="audio"> <td>some data</td> </tr>
<tr class="video"> <td>some data</td> </tr>
<tr class="writing"> <td>some data</td> </tr>
<tr class="game"> <td>some data</td> </tr>
</table>
```

**Desired behaviors**:

1. If no boxes are checked, display all table data
2. If any boxes are checked, hide any unchecked boxes

So far I have this, but how can I find and hide the correct table rows?

```
     $('#music_filter, #video_filter, #writing_filter, #games_filter').on('click',function(){
        var unCheckedlength = $("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").length;
        if (unCheckedlength < 4) {
            var notchecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)")
            for (box in notchecked) {
                    // Needed code to hide unwanted table rows
            }
        } else {
           $('.audio, .writing, .game, .video').show();
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').on('click',()=>{
  let ids = $('input:checked')
    .map( (i,input) => $(input).val()).get()
  $('tr')
    .filter( (i,tr) => !ids.includes($(tr).attr('class'))).hide()
})
```

Each time an input is clicked this will get a list of checkboxes' ids that are checked. Then it will hide all the rows that are not in that list.

Comment: This isn't getting the desired behavior. When I click checkbox it hides appropriately, but when I click/uncheckbox it doesn't respond correctly. It should show all rows again after all boxes are unchecked.

Comment: Also, if I click two or three it should display data for all that are clicked and it doesn't do that.